# Jmeter for localhost giving different results

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm doing a jmeter test the test is on localhost . My testplan is to hit login and then another http request . The test is running and getting response . But when I run the same test again I'm getting different results. I'm doing it in GUI mode . Please help me I'm new to jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You're violating at least 2 main [best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html):

1. JMeter's GUI mode is for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to test execution you must [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/)
2. Having load generator (JMeter) and the system under test on the same machine is not the best idea, both tools may be very resource intensive when it comes to high loads and at some point they will start fighting for the OS resources like CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO, etc. so when it comes to the [bottleneck identification](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/wp-rapid-1.pdf) you will not be able to tell for sure why response times are high or throughput is low as the reasons could be in:

   - JMeter doesn't have enough headroom to operate and cannot send requests fast enough
   - Application cannot respond fast enough due to lack of RAM or CPU overload
   - CPU is constantly [switching the context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) from JMeter to the application under test and vice versa